# nowrap option on a file opened in split window

Tags: split, wrapping

I use `set nowrap` option in my config file, but when I open a file in a vertical split it has no effect.

If I redo `set nowrap` after open the file (in the split windows) it takes effect

Why?
I try with vim and neovim with the same result.

Step to reproduce:

1. `set nowrap`
2. `:vs`
3. open a file with long lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the doc [`:h 'wrap'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27wrap%27):

```
'wrap'          boolean (default on)
                local to window
```

The option is local to a window so setting it in your `vimrc` has no effect to your windows.

You probably want to set the option for a specific file type either in an autocommand [`:h autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd)

```
augroup NoWrap
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype markdown set nowrap
augroup END
```

or (and this is a better solution) in a ftplugin [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)

Comment: For me the better solution is open all file with `nowrap` so I set `autocmd Filetype * set nowrap` in vimrc file